# Analysis of numerical data

Tags: bash, text, numeric

Using some bash script I'd like to perform some kind of the analysis of big log.txt file consisted of the big numbers of strings where each of them are present in the following format

```
PHE 233,R PHE 233,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.07884,0.0296770011962,0.00209848087911,0.023555,0.0757544518494,0.00535664866078,-0.065675,0.0859064571205,0.00607450383776,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.12096,0.0486756448339,0.00344188785407
TYR 234,R TYR 234,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.25531,0.629561517169,0.0445167217964,-0.004085,0.179779219531,0.0127123105246,0.169925,0.199097411774,0.0140783129982,-0.06675426,0.0227214659046,0.00160665026196,-1.15622426,0.59309226863,0.0419379565017
GLY 235,R GLY 235,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.039345,0.0259211491836,0.00183290203639,-0.053115,0.0245550763591,0.00173630610061,0.098535,0.0441429357316,0.00312137691973,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.006075,0.0208364914273,0.00147336243844
THR 236,R THR 236,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.03241,0.0100624003101,0.000711519149426,-0.115375,0.0590932684407,0.00417852508369,0.116505,0.0563931731241,0.00398759951286,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.03128,0.0262172004608,0.00185383602295
```

from each of this line of log.txt I need to get and paste in new log file final_log.txt of only first, second and last terms: In the above case it would be

```
PHE 233 0.00344188785407
TYR 234 0.0419379565017
THR 236 0.00185383602295
```

!! what is most important! because typical logs are consisted of big number of the strings in new txt file I'd like to sort strings in accordance to the value of last term providing choosen threshold for them. Eventually from the log.txt I'd like to select and paste to the final_log.txt of only those strings where the numbers in last column are equal or higher than the defined threshold. I'd be very thankful for any solutions of this non-trivial (for me!) problem.

Gleb

Comment: Even if you feel that the problem is to difficult for you to solve yourself, it's still a good idea to make an attempt and show where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Through awk,

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $1" "$2" "$NF}' file
```

OR

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $1,$2,$NF}' file
PHE 233 0.00344188785407
TYR 234 0.0419379565017
GLY 235 0.00147336243844
THR 236 0.00185383602295
```

Comment: it's strange in my case it produced strings without second column where it was no ',' as the separation: GLU  0.000188139579721